# Probability of winning a contest after people join

Tags: probability

Let $n\geq 1$. A contest has two rounds. You are automatically in the second round, while $n$ other people are in the first round. Each of the $n$ other people proceeds to the second round with probability $1/n$, independently. If there are $k$ people in the second round, you win the contest with probability $1/k$. Is it true that you win the contest with probability at least $1/2$, regardless of $n$?

For $n=1$ it's clear that the probability is exactly $1/2$.

For $n=2$, the probability that both other people join is $1/4$, and in this case you win with probability $1/3$. If one other person joins (probability $1/2$), you win with probability $1/2$. If no one else joins, you win with probability $1$. The probability that you win is then $$\frac14\cdot\frac13+\frac12\cdot\frac12+\frac14\cdot 1=\frac{7}{12}>\frac12.$$

For $n=3$, the probability that you win is 
$$\frac{1}{27}\cdot\frac{1}{4}+\frac{6}{27}\cdot\frac13+\frac{12}{27}\cdot\frac12+\frac{8}{27}=\frac{65}{108}>\frac12.$$

Comment: @JerryGuern See if it's more understandable now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, let $X\sim Binom(n,\frac 1 n)$. Then $$P(Win(n))=E\big(\frac 1 {1+X}\big)\geq\frac 1 {1+E(X)}=\frac 1 2$$ by Jensen's inequality (with equality only if $n=1$).

We can also integrate probability generating function for $X$ from $0$ to $1$ to yield $$P(Win(n))=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac 1 {k+1}P(X=k)=\sum_{k=0}^n\int_0^1P(X=k)z^kdz=\int_0^1 (1-\frac 1 n+\frac z n)^ndz=\frac n {n+1}-\frac{n-1}{n+1}\big(1-\frac 1 n)^n\to 1-e^{-1}$$

Comment: Could you please explain how you arrived at this calculation?

Comment: @Alexi  This is the correct answer, efficiently calculated but light on explanation.  Did his edit clear it up enough?

Answer (score 1):

Let $p_i$ be the probability that $i$ other people reach the second round. The expected number of other people who reach the second round is $1$. Hence $p_0\ge1-p_0-p_1$, so your winning probability is at least

$$
p_0+\frac12p_1\ge\frac12p_0+\frac12p_1+\frac12(1-p_0-p_1)=\frac12
$$

(and this would hold even if you lost if two or more other people reach the second round).

Comment: @A.S.: Thanks, you're right, I've corrected it.